# SoapUI mock service response based on calling test case

Tags: rest, groovy, mocking, soapui

The flow goes like this:

Client RQ-> System Under Test -> backendsystem -> SUT -> Client response

Backend can respond with various errors, and the goal is to test how those errors are propagated to the Client. 
I'm trying to use soapui rest mock to simulate backend system. I have created multiple error response in mock. But the problem is that they are triggered by the same Client RQ. 
The idea is to determined the backend response by the test case that is running.

TC 404: Client RQ -> SUT -> backend mock response 404 -> SUT -> Client -> assert 404

TC no data: Client RQ -> SUT -> backend mock response no data -> SUT -> Client -> assert no data error
...

Since the Client RQ is the same for each TC the only way for dynamic selection of backed mock response is to know which TC is running.

The bottom question is how to pass testRunner.testCase object to the mock response dispatcher script

Comment: What type of `mock dispatcher` are you using? Can you not identify what to return in the response based on the request?

Comment: As I stated, the request is the same for all cases, so there is no option to choose response based on request.

Comment: Hope request may be same, but you can use different value for some element, so that it is easy to identify? Does it make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately no. As you can see I do not make send the request to the backend system. The SUT does and I do not have a control on it. I make a call to SUT, SUT make the call to the backend. I will go with sequence dispatch, and configure SUT to do only one retry. Then I will make the same order of the request with right assertion and mock response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

1. You will not be able to find the test case name in the mock service.
2. However, if you want test case name only, and there is no ther way to identify, then you can send the test case name as http header value to the mock service. For example, add header name 'TC_NAME' and value as 'TC1'.
3. http header can be read in mock dispatcher `SCRIPT` using below sample script:

```groovy
log.info mockRequest.requestHeaders['TC_NAME'][0]
 //read the request header in the mock service
def tcName = mockRequest.requestHeaders['TC_NAME'][0]
def responseFile
if (tcName == 'TC1') {
    responseFile = '/set/your/right/response/for/tc1_response.xml'
} else if (tcName =='TC2'){
    responseFile = '/set/your/right/response/for/tc2_response.xml'
} else {
  //set default file as response
   responseFile = '/set/your/right/response/for/default_response.xml'
}
context.content = new File(responseFile).text
```

In the mock response, just add `${content}`, so that the data can be loaded from the dynamic file based on the condition and set it as response content.

You may also find some similar example [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-get-soap-mock-response-from-external-file/m-p/110795#M19159)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It wont work in my case as I sending the request to SUT and the SUT send the request to the mocked backed. I can set the header in the request to SUT but I cannot set the header in the request that SUT makes to the backed mock.

Comment: However I'm accepting your answer since there is no way to access testRunner in mock service, and your answer contain very useful peace of knowledge. Thanks